# Condição não entra conforme a digitação

Tags: python, string, if

Não importa o que eu digite está caindo no primeiro `if`, se eu digitar m, M ou até mesmo 10 cairá no primeiro `if`. Quero que se o usuário digitar f ou F apareça feminino e o mesmo valendo para M ou m.

```
Letra = str(input("Qual seu gênero:"))
if Letra == "F" or "f":
    print("Feminino")
elif Letra == "M" or "m":
    print("Masculino")
else:
    ("sexo invalido")
```

Comment: o correto seria, comparação or comparação

Comment: Quando faz `if Letra == "F" or "f":` é o mesmo que fazer `if (Letra == "F") or true:` e independente do resultado lógico da premissa `(Letra == "F")` qualquer coisa testada com a preposição `or true` sempre retornará `true` implicando que a sentença `Letra == "F" or "f"` sempre retorne true e o `if` caia sempre no primeiro caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve fazer a comparação completa, não funciona do jeito que está imaginando. O `or` espera como operando de cada lado um resultado booleano. Uma das formas de se obter um é fazendo uma operação de comparação, como fez na primeira comparação testando se a variável é igual a um determinado texto. Na segunda comparação do `or` não está testando nada, está só colocando `"f"`, nada é comparado de fato, não há uma operação que resulte em um booleano.

Python é uma linguagem de tipagem forte, mais ou menos, tem uns casos que ela pisa na bola aí, e este é um deles. Python decidiu que qualquer valor exceto alguns poucos específicos seriam considerados verdadeiro se esperar um valor booleano e é isto que acontecer `"f"` é considerado `True` e em uma comparação de `or` tudo o que tem `True` de um dos lados é considerado `True` e por isso entra no bloco do `if`. Mudando para uma comparação com o operador de igualdade (`==`) ele realmente verifica se aquilo é ´igual e aí opera corretamente e dá o resultado que espera.

Sugiro estudar lógica booleana e entender como os *tokens* das linguagens funcionam. Não existe mágica no código escrito, tem regras bem definidas do porquê de cada coisa, não acontece por acaso por isso que sempre falo para as pessoas aprofundarem mais do que o que é visto na superfície, caso contrário sempre "programará" na tentativa e erro, conseguirá fazer algumas coisas funcionarem, mas nunca entenderá porque, não conseguirá criar coisas novas.

```
letra = input("Qual seu gênero:")
if letra == "F" or letra == "f":
    print("Feminino")
elif letra == "M" or letra == "m":
    print("Masculino")
else:
    ("sexo invalido")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oAu5bj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/OrConditionpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/OrCondition.py).

Aproveitei e simplifiquei o código.

Comment: Certo eu entendi, mas pq não posso fazer como no meu exemplo. tipo if letra == "f" or "F".

Comment: @RennanFelipe eu ainda estava terminando a resposta, veja agora

Answer (score 3):

Quando você testa simplesmente F sem comparar com Letra sem pre será verdadeiro.

```
if Letra == "F" or "f": # Isto está teoricamente errado.
```

Quando você testa simplesmente M sem comparar com Letra sem pre será verdadeiro.

```
elif Letra == "M" or "m": # Isto está teoricamente errado.
```

A forma correta seria:

```
Letra = str(input("Qual seu gênero:"))
if Letra == "F" or Letra == "f":
    print("Feminino")
elif Letra == "M" or Letra == "m":
    print("Masculino")
else:
    ("sexo invalido")
```

Espero ter ajudado...